# How to fix KeyError: 'Id' in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a project which uses facial recognition to record class attendance. The second block of codes below are for tracking(recognizing the faces in the video feed) but i keep getting the error in the third block. I think it has to do with my indexing and I'm not sure where the problem is coming from.

This is the code i used forcreating the StudentDetails.csv

```
 res = "Images Saved for ID : " + Id +" Name : "+ name
        row = [Id, name]
        with open('StudentDetails\StudentDetails.csv','a+') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
            writer.writerow(row)
        csvFile.close()
        message.configure(text= res)
    else:
        if(is_number(Id)):
            res = "Enter Alphabetical Name"
            message.configure(text= res)
        if(name.isalpha or name.isspace()):
            res = "Enter Numeric Id"
            message.configure(text= res)
```

This the block of code for tracking

```
def TrackImages():
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()#cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    recognizer.read("TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath);    
    df=pd.read_csv("StudentDetails\StudentDetails.csv")
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX        
    col_names =  ['Id','Name','Date','Time']
    attendance = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)    
    while True:
        ret, img =cam.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)    
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])                                   
            if(conf < 50):
                ts = time.time()      
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt=str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendance.loc[len(attendance)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]
                
               
                
            else:
                Id='Unknown'                
                tt=str(Id)  
            if(conf > 75):
                noOfFile=len(os.listdir("ImagesUnknown"))+1
                cv2.imwrite("ImagesUnknown\Image"+str(noOfFile) + ".jpg", im[y:y+h,x:x+w])            
            cv2.putText(img,str(tt),(x,y+h), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
            
        attendance=attendance.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='first')    
        cv2.imshow('frame',img) 
        if (cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
            break
    ts = time.time()      
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    Hour,Minute,Second=timeStamp.split(":")
    fileName="Attendance\Attendance_"+date+"_"+Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
    attendance.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #print(attendance)
    res=attendance
    message2.configure(text= res)
```

This is the error i got for this code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IFEANYI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IFEANYI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\IFEANYI\Documents\yr 4 semester 2\FR2\ifeanyi train.py", line 184, in TrackImages
    aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
  File "C:\Users\IFEANYI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\IFEANYI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in strong textpandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Id'
```

This is a snapshot of StudentDetails.csv
[StudentDetails.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZZj.png)

Comment: your source/data dataframe is missing a column named `Id`. It may b typo :P

Comment: okay but how do i fix it

Comment: What are the column names for the "StudentDetails.csv"? You do no explicitly set those names and so the column names are assumed by pandas when the csv is read. You can specify column names at that point, see the pandas documentation for all option. In the future I recommend including a snippet of the sample data to help people answer your question

Comment: first check what columns you have in `print( df.columns )` if you don't have `Id` then create this column or rename other column. All depends what you have in `df` which you didn't show.

Comment: okay i have also added a snippet of StudentDetails.csv

Comment: lol .. can show raw data from `StudentDetails.csv` i.e. **column header** + a couple of rows with sample data.